# Different NODE_ENV for different tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest, superagent

I'm testing my API with [**supertest**](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest)

I want to check that my CSRF token protection works, and then disable it for the other tests.

For this I set `NODE_ENV` to `test` or `not_test`

**app.js**

```
var csrf = require('csurf');   
var app  = express();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
  app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }));
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
    return next();
  });
}
```

**Test CSRF**

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'not_test';

var app = require("app.js");
var request = require('supertest')(app);

var testAccount = {
  "login": "test",
  "pass": "test"
};

describe('CSRF protection', function() {
  it('On /login', function(done){
    request
      .post('/login')
      .send(testAccount)
      .expect(403, done);
  });
});
```

**Test login**
NODE_ENV is now *test*

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

var app = require("app.js");
var request = require('supertest').agent(app);

var testAccount = {
  "login": "test",
  "pass": "test"
};

describe('API Admin roads', function() {
  before(function (done) {
    request
      .post('/login')
      .send(testAccount)
      .end(done);
  });

  it('/api/admin/groups/', function(done){
    request
      .get('/api/admin/groups/')
      .expect(200, done);
  });
});
```

The problem is, only the first `process.env.NODE_ENV` is taken into account, if I set it to `not_test` and then to `test` I will still be in `not_test` mode.

Comment: Hey Why don't you change the process.env.NODE_ENV in the before function and the after function?

Comment: @itai Because `process.env.NODE_ENV` need to be set before `app.js` is included as the test `NODE_ENV !== 'test'` is done in `app.js`

Comment: i have an idea but never tried it my self.Not sure if it's good one. maybe trying to require inside the describe scope ( I know it's not recommended in real web server but maybe it will work and would be just good enough to this test) -it might wrote a shot?

Comment: same problem, adding `console.log("ENV : " + process.env.NODE_ENV);` in app.js only display one line (although there is 2 tests from 2 differents files run). I guess the `require('app.js');` is kept in cache

Comment: `delete require.cache[require.resolve("app.js")]` makes it work !!!

Comment: just saw that in online search :)

Answer (score 1):

Tests can be executed in many ways and their execution sequence isn't always the same (e.g. [mocha --parallel](https://mochajs.org/#parallel-tests) option).

So, rewriting a shared variable like `process.env` and manipulating the `require` cache it's not a reliable way to solve this problem. It's an hack - today it works but it will broke easily when you (or your workmates) will change the code tomorrow.

An easier and cleaner way to do that, is to return an *init function* from your `app.js` file and get the `app` object as the output of this function call. In this way you can pass to it an **explicit** option to enable/disable the csrf token protection:

```
//app.js
module.exports = function appSetup(opts) {
  var csrf = require('csurf');   
  var app  = express();

  if (opts.csrfEnabled) {
    app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }));
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
      return next();
    });
  }

  // more express handlers ...
  // app.use(...)

  return app;
}
```

Then disable it in your tests without csrf:

```
var app = require("app.js");
var request = require('supertest')(app({csrfEnabled: false}));
```

And enable it where you need it:

```
var app = require("app.js");
var request = require('supertest')(app({csrfEnabled: true}));
```

Obviously you need to update you app start code, e.g. `bin/start.js`:

```
var app = require('../app')({csrfEnabled: true});
var server = http.createServer(app);
// and so on...
```

Advantages of this approach:

- no specific execution order required
- no concurrency problems
- explicit setup of your app